# Change Application Name of a Verified App - Google OAuth Consent Screen

Tags: google-oauth, developer-console

I have a verified app and I would like to change the OAuth consent screen application name(only application name).

In order to do this, it seems that I need to reverify this again, but my app is ALREADY in production now, if I submit it for verification would the current verified OAuth screen suddenly be shown as unverified, OR is there any way to show the old OAuth screen until the new one is verified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always re-apply for verification at any time. The previous approved state of your app will hold.

- If you are applying for brand verification [1], any previously approved brand information will continue to be displayed until you complete the new verification
- If you are requesting new sensitive scopes [2], only the previously approved sensitive scopes will be displayed without an unverified screen. Any requests containing new sensitive scopes will show an unverified app screen until approved. See [How to resubmit for google oauth verification if changes in scope without disturbing the production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086559/how-to-resubmit-for-google-oauth-verification-if-changes-in-scope-without-distur/56094789#56094789) for good practices on getting verification without affecting all your users.

[1] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#verification-types

[2] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#sensitive-restricted-scopes