# Google OAuth App re-verification on scope addition

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have an Google client App which we are using in production currently and now we need to add a new scope(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send) to it which is a sensitive one. For this we need to apply for verification and I am confused with the steps to do it.
The documentation says:

- Show that the OAuth Consent Screen correctly displays the App Name.
- Show that the URL bar of the OAuth Consent Screen correctly includes your app’s Client ID.

If my App is currently in production how can I add a sensitive scope to it and create a video?
Is there any way to create a video without taking my App off production in this scenario?

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209151/change-application-name-of-a-verified-app-google-oauth-consent-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086559/how-to-resubmit-for-google-oauth-verification-if-changes-in-scope-without-distur/56094789#56094789) but didn't get the proper info for this scenario. But I feel this is very generic case and most of the organisations would have faced this.

Comment: I have added a comment to both of the questions you have linked neither will work anymore for the reasons you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> If my App is currently in production how can I add a sensitive scope to it and create a video? Is there any way to create a video without taking my App off production in this scenario?

Your going to have to add the new scope to your project on Google cloud console, and then create the video showing your application using the sensitive scope as instructed.

- make sure your browser window is sent to english
- run your application and show the consent screen where it displays the scopes
- and make sure to get a shot of the URL bar where your client id is displayed in the url.

Unfortunately this will probably knock your project out of verification and impact the fact that your application is currently running in production.   As far as i know Google does not have any guidelines to existing verified in production applications requesting additional scopes.

If your issue is with development google recommends having a second project that you can use in the testing stage to develop on  your application and then move to the new client when you are ready to go to production.   This does not however answer how to request additional scopes without breaking your production client.

I am going to contact Google directly for some advice. I will let you know if i hear anything.

Comment: Please let me know once you hear something back from Google on this. For the time being it seems the only solution is to go with a parallel client with additional scopes.

Comment: Unfortunately my google contact is still trying to find a contact at google who could even answer this question.   This may take a while.

Comment: Did you ever receive an answer to this? I am experiencing the exact same situation and can't figure out how to get the app reverified after adding new sensitive scopes!

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo did you get any updates regarding existing verified apps in production requesting additional scopes? Does it break? thanks

Comment: Dont know I have another contact I can try.