# Scopes and dependencies/overlaps

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

We are currently under verification of our application. We are reviewing all the scopes that have been granted for our app.

For example, in **Gmail API** we are currently approved for the following scopes by **Google Team** before. We are currently evaluating whether we need other scopes.

| Sensitivity | API | Scope | User-facing description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Restricted scopes | Gmail API | mail google com | Read, compose, send, and permanently delete all your email from Gmail |
| Restricted scopes | Gmail API | auth gmail modify | Read, compose, and send emails from your Gmail account |
| Restricted scopes | Gmail API | auth gmail compose | Manage drafts and send emails |

Are there any dependencies between scopes? Let's say we removed **"auth/gmail compose"** from our scopes, will that cause an error because "mail google com" might be dependent on the preceding scope mentioned?

If we remove the other scopes from our app verification and asked the Google Team to approve it, will that throw an error on our already released app? We are worried that it may affect some of our users who rely on Google Services.

Thanks to anyone for replying and your help.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you need a particular scope depends on the API you are using. The API documentation will tell you whether it needs one scope or multiple scopes (the latter being atypical). So if you want to remove the gmail.compose scope, it will not prevent you from calling any APIs that accept the full mail scope (mail.google.com), including some APIs that may have accepted the gmail.compose scope.

Removing scopes from your app, however, must be done carefully. If you are changing to new scopes that you weren't previously approved for, [see this answer for some approaches to take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086559/how-to-resubmit-for-google-oauth-verification-if-changes-in-scope-without-distur/56094789#56094789). Making changes to the scope you request (with unapproved scopes) will result in a user seeing the unverified app screen. There will be no impact to existing users who already granted access to the app, as long as you're only requesting new access tokens for them using the previously obtained refresh token/consent.