Adding sensitive permission scope to existing google app in production - would it break existing users?
We are trying to add sensitive scope for gmail to our existing set of permissions to our gmail app  that is already in production and thousands of users are using the app.
If we add the scope, will existing app go into unverified status until that additional sensitive scope is verified?
What's the best way to approach this so that existing live app continues working for all current users? Thanks!
Read the documentation - https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/13464018?sjid=17021978333350096407-NC

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086559/how-to-resubmit-for-google-oauth-verification-if-changes-in-scope-without-distur/56094789#56094789
